# Retry mechanism and timedout messages

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, network-programming

I'm implementing a provisioning system on a Linux server, the code is huge so I'm going to put the algorithm, it works as like this

```
1. Read provisioning commands from file
2. Send it to another server using TCP 
3. Save the request in hash.
4. Receive the response then
    A. if successful response received then remove request from hash 
    B. if failed response received then retry the message
```

The problem I'm in now is when the program didn't receive the response for a timeout reason then the request will be waiting for a response forever and won't be retried.

I tried to use timer but that didn't help because I'll end up with so many waiting timers and I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing this.

The question is how can I save the message in some data structure and check to remove or retry it later when there is no response from the other end?

Comment: You want to build something asycnhronous?

Comment: I'm not how to build that.

Comment: So if you were using Java there are frameworks. google on if you can do something asynchronously in C. So that you have a callback fn for the response.

Comment: @user_iv, How about having the server send a response always? A timeout = failure by and large, so send the failure message back to the requester maybe?

Comment: @Anish, I have no control over the server and I've seen timeouts due to network issues.

Comment: @smk, I'm not sure how callback would help here?

Comment: @user_iv then you dont need to keep timers waiting right?

Comment: The reason I thought of timers is because I don't know other way that free my resources if there is no response for my request. but please let me know if you have another way to solve it even if I need to use something else other than hash.

Comment: You may want to use multiplexing syscalls (with some delay) like `poll(2)`  to check if a file descriptor (e.g. a socket) has some readable data (or can be written into). I suggest reading a good book like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: No, Sorry but poll has nothing to do with this.